# Reading and converting to data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I just imported a csv file as a data frame. I did this.

```
myframe <- data.frame(read.csv("afile.csv"))
```

but when I use the 'typeof()' function on 'myframe', I get a list.

```
> typeof(myframe)
[1] "list"
```

'myframe' turns out to be a nested list. Trying to change the name of the 9th list in the myframe does absolutely nothing. I don't even get an error. This is my code.

```
colnames(myframe[9]) <- "ColName"
```

I am not able to convert this list to a data frame either (No matter what I do). Any method I try throws up no errors and yet does nothing. I tried this.

```
myframe <- as.data.frame(myframe)
```

and

```
myframe  <-  as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(myframe), nrow=length(unlist(myframe[1]))))
```

(as suggested on a different post)

So this is basically a 4 part question,

1. Is my R behaving as expected?
2. Why isn't an error being returned?
3. How can change the name of that column?
4. How do I convert the nested list to a data frame?

Comment: The `read.csv` gives a `data.frame`.  You don't need to wrap with `data.frame`. The second part should be `colnames(myframe)[9] <- "ColName"`  You can check the `str(myframe)` after doing `myframe <- read.csv("afile.csv")` or check `is.data.frame(myframe)` the `typeof(myframe)` always returns a `list` as `data.frame` is a `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues in the OP's post.

1. Reading as a data.frame

   The `read.csv` gives a `data.frame` output.   So, there is no need to wrap with `data.frame` i.e.

   ```
   myframe <- read.csv("afile.csv")
   ```

   If the delimiter is different, use the `sep` argument and also for non-numeric variables, the default option (because `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`) for `read.csv` will be to return the `class` as `factor`.  In that case, use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`.
2. Changing the column names in the dataset.  This can be done by selecting the column names that we want to change.  As we are changing the 9th column name, select that by indexing and then assign (`<-`) it to new name.

   ```
   colnames(myframe)[9] <- "ColName"
   ```
3. By checking the `typeof(myframe)`, it will give `"list"` as `data.frame` is a `list` with `length` of the `list` elements equal.  If we want to check whether it is a `data.frame`

   ```
   is.data.frame(myfile)
   ```

   or

   ```
   str(myframe)
   ```
4. Error message are returned only when there is an `error`.  Here, it won't give an error as you are wrapping a `data.frame` by a `data.frame` call.  For example

   ```
   df1 <- data.frame(v1 = 1:5)
   str(df1)
   #'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
   #$ v1: int  1 2 3 4 5
   ```

   Wrapping with `data.frame` is not going to change anything except that it is redundant.  Of course, we can do `data.frame(data.frame(data.frame(df1)))` to test as an exercise.

   ```
   str(data.frame(df1))
   #'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
   #$ v1: int  1 2 3 4 5
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I was basically doing a whole bunch of things wrong. I still don't understand, if this was wrong ' colnames(myframe[9]) <- "ColName" ', why wasn't an error thrown up? What is the code doing here?

Comment: @krthkskmr You are subsetting the dataset by doing `myframe[9]` and then assigning the `colnames` on that subset is not going to reflect on the original dataset.  Instead subset the colnames

Answer (score 0):

The default storing of file is a dataframe. No need to make it a dataframe.

```
    myframe <- read.csv(file.choose(),sep=",",header=T) #Select your file interactively.
    class(myframe)       
    mode(myframe)
    typeof(myframe)
    names(myframe)[9] <- "ColName"   ## Renaming column no. 9 of dataframe
```